# In Russian, can "мы" be used to refer to "you" in conversation?

Tags: грамматика

> А чего это **мы** такие ворчливые?

I just received an IM from my girlfriend, in which she used the pronoun "мы" (jokingly, I suppose) although it was I alone who was grumbling about something in a previous message.

I wonder if this is an equivalent of "Aren't **we** grumpy today?" in English and "**On** est ronchon, hein ?" in French? English and French use the pronouns "we/on" to indirectly refer to "you/tu" respectively.

Comment: example from a movie [***"Может помолчим?"***](https://youtu.be/5Id0W16WK-4?t=13m56s)

Comment: just wanted to span you a bit, since noting you got into Italian: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbVdfcQn4gY - this video channel might be of some recreational value and at the same time match parts of both Russian and Italian cultures, which your profile says are yet two least mastered languages of yours

Answer (score 18):

In this particular case it means "Why are you grumpy today"? So, "we" means "you" in this sentence.

This form is often used when talking to children and emphasizes jocular tone.

Comment: *This form is often used when talking to children* this is true for English as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in sentences like this “мы” can in fact be a 2nd person pronoun.

Also observe that this can apply to imperative mood as well. “Проходим, не задерживаемся!”

Answer (score 3):

The usage of **мы** instead of **ты**/**вы** in colloquial speech is wide enough. The explorers call it '**sympathetically intimate**', '**solidary**', '**doctorate** / **parental**' or '**inclusive**'. Such a usage of **мы** is considered *neutral* when it emphasizes a definitely higher situational status of the speaker, e. g. in a pair like **doctor-to-patient** (К*ак мы себя чувствуем?*), **parent-to-child** (*Что это мы тут плачем?*),  **policeman-to-suspect** (*Будем сознаваться или будем играть в молчанку!?*), etc. A *comical* effect only appears if it's spoken by someone 'out of proper status'.

> (В. З. Санников, Русский язык в зеркале языковой игры)
>
> https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=cRyLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=da9xaO3W0Q&sig=ACfU3U3d6nZJB4gbAygeQnAmbbQuOkLgaw&w=1280
>
> https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=cRyLAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=da9xaO3W0Q&sig=ACfU3U3P472gku_DWe20h6Yugnm_BFiFzQ&w=1280

Comment: it also sounds condescending and patronizing

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if this is an equivalent of "Aren't we grumpy today?" in English.

I think this is exact equivalent.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer as it doesn't _explain_ anything about the answer. Adding why it is the way it is, when to use or not use this form, etc. would make this a proper answer.